# How to insert and delete text in vi on Debian 9

Tags: debian, vi

I have only used vi on Debain 8 before and I was able to press "i" to add any text. Even delete was working fine. But now on Debian 9 it seems vi behaviour is different as pressing "i" nothing happens.

On Debian 8 when you press "i" then it says at the bottom "INSERT" which means now you can start changing text. On Debian 9 pressing "i" does nothing but if I press it twice then it shows one "i" and then I can write remaining text.

Right now I just want to change SSH port and for that I simply want to delete character "#" and change port 22 to something else but I can't even do this simple task now.

Is there a command tutorial available for vi on Debian 9?

Comment: esc esc i does it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, on Debian 9, `/usr/bin/vi` is a symlink to `vim` or `vim-tiny` in version 8.0, while on Debian 8 it's been a symlink to version 7.4. Absolutely nothing has changed about the absolute basic commands like `i` or `x`. Even in readonly mode (option `-R` or started with command `view`) the commands work, just issuing a warning about changing a readonly file. Even the horrible "easy" mode (option `-y`) doesn't produce behaviour like you describe.

Bottom line: This is not caused by simply switching from Debian 8 to 9.

What to do:

- `type vi` will tell you what you are actually executing, for example `/usr/bin/vi`
- `vi --version` should tell you what you are really executing
- If it's really some `vi` or `vim`, you are using some really weird keybindings! Test whether it's local or global by trying as another user

**Update after reading OP's comment:**

"*On Debian 9 pressing "i" does nothing but if I press it twice then it shows one "i" and then I can write remaining text.*", so pressing <kbd>i</kbd> actually does something: it puts you in insert mode as before. You are just irritated because nothing is displayed in the last line. In this respect there should also not be any differences between Debian 8 and 9.

Two possible causes for this behaviour:

- You have set *noshowmode* somewhere in your `~/.vimrc` or some other configuration source. Type `:set showmode` or `:set smd` and see whether the behaviour is as you are used to. If yes, check for `set nosmd` or `noshowmode` in your or the system's `vim` configuration and remove it.
- Or the locale you are using is defect. Do `LANG=C` and then start `vi`.

Answer (score 4):

The top answer hints at the issue, but the problem is specifically that the default configuration in this version of Debian is the vim.tiny configuration.  If you download the vim.basic configuration and use that instead, it will work as expected.

```
apt-get install vim
```

Then, check that vim.basic is selected:

```
update-alternatives --config vi
```

Comment: As a linux newbie, this had confused me for a while. I'd connect to a machine and use vi, but it was kinda sorta broken. This was exactly the reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you have vi/vim installed then `vimtutor` should be on your machine, just enter that at the command line and follow the walkthrough.

If you are familiar with `vi` then try `vim`, which is an improved `vi` but uses substantially the same controls, and see if that works as expected.

The behaviour of `i`/`esc` to get in and out of edit mode should not have changed with the kernel update.

Comment: On Debian 8 when you press "i" then it says at the bottom "INSERT" which means now you can start changing text. On Debian 9 pressing "i" does nothing but if I press it twice then it shows one "i" and then I can write remaining text. I got the hang of it but I went ahead and used nano as suggested by @saga